# MongoDB index not covering trivial query

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am working on a `MongoDB` application, and am having trouble with covered queries. After reworking many of my queries to perform better when paginating I found that my previously covered queries were no longer being covered by the index. I tried to distill the working set down as far as possible to isolate the issue but I'm still confused.

First, on a fresh (empty) collection, I inserted the following documents:

```
devdb> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53157aa0dd2cab043ab92c14"), "metadata" : { "created_by" : "bcheng" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53157aa6dd2cab043ab92c15"), "metadata" : { "created_by" : "albert" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53157aaadd2cab043ab92c16"), "metadata" : { "created_by" : "zzzzzz" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53157aaedd2cab043ab92c17"), "metadata" : { "created_by" : "thomas" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53157ab9dd2cab043ab92c18"), "metadata" : { "created_by" : "bbbbbb" } }
```

Then, I created an index for the 'metadata.created_by' field:

```
devdb> db.test.getIndices()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "devdb.test",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "metadata.created_by" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "devdb.test",
                "name" : "metadata.created_by_1"
        }
]
```

Now, I tried to lookup a document by the field:

```
devdb> db.test.find({'metadata.created_by':'bcheng'},{'_id':0,'metadata.created_by':1}).sort({'metadata.created_by':1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor metadata.created_by_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "metadata.created_by" : [
                        [
                                "bcheng",
                                "bcheng"
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "localhost:27017"
}
```

The correct index is being used and no extraneous documents are being scanned. Regardless of the presence of `.hint()`, `limit()`, or `sort()`, `indexOnly` remains `false`.

Digging through the documentation, I've seen that covered indices will fail to cover queries on array elements, but that isn't the case here (and `isMultiKey` shows `false`).

What am I missing? Are there other reasons for this behavior (eg. insuffient RAM, disk space, etc.)? And if so, how can I best diagnose these issues in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not supported. See this [Jira issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2104).

Comment: Well, that certainly answers the question. Thanks for the quick reply!